# MySQL populate column as sum of constituent table column

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL DB with 2 tables. The first contains time and distance information between two points. The second table contains the atomic instructions that collectively form the master time and distance information. For example, the master holds the high level data on going from Paris to Lille (total distance, time etc) and the second table (leg_table) contains the exact roads to take with their individual time and distances. I wish to check that the table has been populated correctly.

I wish to populate a column in the master table that is the sum of all the relevant leg_table parts. The Primary key in the master is the foreign key in the second table. The leg_table data is of variable length (e.g. some routes contain 2 legs, others many more).

I tried the following:

```
update master set master.distance_check = (select sum(leg_table.leg_distance from leg_table where leg_table.request_no = master.request_no));
```

But I get:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000):
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update with join statement is incorrect, you may try as

```
update master m 
join (
 select sum(leg_distance) as leg_distance,request_no
 from leg_table 
 group by request_no
)l 
on m.request_no = l.request_no
set m.distance_check = l.leg_distance
```